# Does mission order-of-completion matter?

Tags: splinter-cell-blacklist

I've started a new game of splinter cell blacklist, and so far only completed the first 2 campaign missions. (Intro + Save Andriy)

What I'm wondering is, should I be completing all option missions + all character conversations in between each campaign mission.

Aside from not earning the extra cash, will I miss out on anything in the storyline, that I can't get back to if I don't complete them as they're available. Or can I just wait til the end.

Answer (score 1):

You might have completed the game by now. But the optional missions are small side missions that interact indirectly with the main mission and story. They are not a must do, but a nice to do.

These missions are introduced via the conversations you can have with the crew unboard Echelon.

I whont get into details regarding the optional missions, those are for you to experience. But I would recommend doing so, as minor details are revealed.

The main story are in the main missions, so you will not miss out on anything.

Answer (score -1):

The option missions are exactly how they sound, optional. The order of which you complete them is your choice and they are a story in their own, not tied in with the campaign, really. However, complete the character conversations, you won't be able to recover those once you start another mission/complete it. The dialogue then goes on to a different script.

Comment: The optional missions are related to the base story line. So this is not true. Each optional mission has minor information about the main mission about the Blacklist.